# Device node LVM

Tags: lvm

There is mention of a device node, when I was reading about LVM.  I can't find anything useful as to what it is or functions as.  Any help or suggestion of where to look would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is basically the `/dev/VGname/LVname`  and `/dev/mapper/` ,that it is being created when you create the and LVM structure. It called device node since it is under the `/dev` node.

So the question is, why is the `/dev` node it there ? Simple answer is that it is intended to be used as a convenient why for you to specify the device in the `fstab` file and the like.

The `udev` system is responsible for the creation of this nodes, and here is some points of why you want it to create them.

> The primary role of the udev device manager is to provide a dynamic
>   way of setting up nodes in the /dev directory. The creation of these
>   nodes is directed by the application of udev rules in userspace. These
>   rules are processed on udev events sent from the kernel directly as a
>   result of adding, removing or changing particular devices. This
>   provides a convenient and central mechanism for hotplugging support.
>
> Besides creating the actual nodes, the udev device manager is able to
>   create symbolic links which the user can name. This provides users the
>   freedom to choose their own customized naming and directory structure
>   in the/dev directory, if needed. Each udev event contains basic
>   information about the device being processed, such as its name, the
>   subsystem it belongs to, the device's type, its major and minor number
>   used, and the type of the event. Given that, and having the
>   possibility of accessing all the information found in the /sys
>   directory that is also accessible within udev rules, the users are
>   able to utilize simple filters based on this information and run the
>   rules conditionally based on this information. The udev device manager
>   also provides a centralized way of setting up the nodes' permissions.
>   A user can easily add a customized set of rules to define the
>   permissions for any device specified by any bit of information that is
>   available while processing the event. It is also possible to add
>   program hooks in udev rules directly.
>
> The udev device manager can call
>   these programs to provide further processing that is needed to handle
>   the event. Also, the program can export environment variables as a
>   result of this processing. Any results given can be used further in
>   the rules as a supplementary source of information. Any software using
>   the udev library is able to receive and process udev events with all
>   the information that is available, so the processing is not bound to
>   the udev daemon only.
>
> In Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 `and its clones`, the Device Mapper provides 
>   direct
>   support for udev integration. This synchronizes the Device Mapper with
>   all udev processing related to Device Mapper devices, including LVM
>   devices. The synchronization is needed since the rule application in
>   the udev daemon is a form of parallel processing with the program that
>   is the source of the device's changes (such as dmsetup and LVM).
>   Without this support, it was a common problem for a user to try to
>   remove a device that was still open and processed by udev rules as a
>   result of a previous change event; this was particularly common when
>   there was a very short time between changes for that device.

Comment: It is called a device node because that is what it is ( ls -l shows 'b' as the first char of the mode, for block device ), not because it is in the /dev directory.